# CIDRAM on Drupal 7

Tags: 7, hooks

Has anyone installed CIDRAM (access management to block undesirable IP addresses) on Drupal 7.

It requires adding a "php require" statement to a file that is executed on every attempt to access the web site, and I do not know which file to use.
Any advice gratefully received.

Frank

Comment: Use [hook_init](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_init/7&ved=2ahUKEwi6sNmU_KniAhWH_J4KHf5qB2YQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw15GtRh0M2mNPugt_J3dxEe&cshid=1558350577717). Create a custom module. In your .module file use this hook.

Comment: `hook_init()` doesn't run on cached pages, but `hook_boot()` runs on all requests that get routed to Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the [ip_ranges](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_ranges) module is a lot more used and easier to setup.

Try to install that module, should be quite easy to configure.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have placed the line

```
require DRUPAL_ROOT . '/pah_to_file/loader.php';
```

in the index.php file at the top level of the drupal files.

It works well!!